# Visual Studio 2012 - Item Template to "Add" context menu

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, ide

I succeed to create and add new Item Template to Visual Studio 2012.

Now I am able to create that new item, using the right click in **"Solution Explorer\Add\New Item"** dialog.

But how I can add this Item Template to appear directly in **"Add"** context menu?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you find how to do that since then?