# Add Visual Studio Item Template to Add dialog on Specific Folder generated from Project Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, itemtemplate, project-template

If I create a MVC Project in Visual Studio, I can right click on the folder `Controllers` and get a custom dialog in the `Add` submenu which very nicely recommends adding a `Controller`:

[image]

**How do I do this for my VS Project Template and Item Template?**

- I have a 2017 VS Project template that creates the folder `Jobs`
- I have a 2017 VS Item template that exposes a new Item `Job`

How can I register that I want the Job Item Template to appear first when a user clicks on the `Jobs` folder and navigates to the Add submenu?

--

Similar questions:

- Targets VS 2012 and no answers [Visual Studio 2012 - Item Template to "Add" context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419688/visual-studio-2012-item-template-to-add-context-menu)
- Targets VS 2012 and answer describes how to add a custom tool, not ad an Item Template to Add dialog menu [Add an Item to the visual studio folder right-click menu within AddIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566315/add-an-item-to-the-visual-studio-folder-right-click-menu-within-addin)

Comment: I've been poking around the VS Templates for asp.net core, but don't see anything customizing the behavior of the Controllers folder: https://github.com/aspnet/Templates